# Multiple Cursors DB Connections Python

Tags: python, sql

I have three DB connections, and this means I have 3 cursor connections.

Is there a way I can combine all 3 of these into one cursor?

I need to use the cursor to query some SQL, the queries utilise parts of each database connection, not sure how I go about this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in some more detail?

Comment: Short answer, no. longer answer, why ?

Comment: Don't think so, since by definition they are independent. You can always programatically "merge" them on your side, tough.